# NTP NIC binding

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vlan, ntp, nic, bindings

I'm wondering whether it's possible to setup NTP on a Windows Server running 2012 R2. The catch is that I only want one of the two NICs on the server to be used for NTP.

Here's a little more information on why I've been asked to set it up this way. We have two virtual networks setup in our environment. One of which is our company data network 192.168.15.0/24 and an engineering network used for plant machinery and engineering workstations 192.168.9.0/24.

Future plans are for the networks to segregated but before this happens the engineering network needs an NTP server for the plant equipment (at the minute they can see our current NTP server on the 192.168.15.0/24 network.

We have an engineering Windows Server 2012 R2 server running SQL and other applications for the engineering team which has two NICs, one for each network.

Now I want to configure the server to be an NTP server and I have configured this using the information in this link, https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/creating-standalone-ntp-server-windows/. However, when presenting this to my line manager he's asked me to look at binding the NTP server to the engineering NIC as he doesn't want any device on the company data network to start picking up it's time from the NIC on the engineering network.

Hopefully this make sense, is this possible? does he have reason to be concerned regarding devices on the 192.168.15.0/24 range to pickup it's time from a server on the 192.168.9.0/24 range?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. You can setup NTP on your server and then access the NTP service from any of the LAN segments you want. If you want to restrict NTP functionality towards one of the segments just use firewall settings and disallow the NTP port.

Comment: Thanks Overmind, I ended up configuring the firewall as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this by using the Windows Firewall to block connections from certain network segments for the NTP services.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Luke try this from Technet some time ago

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/81f70aa9-2e37-482e-a32a-e8679256e7ff/time-service-and-multiple-adapters?forum=winserverManagement